# Typo3 9 - clear cache for a page id

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

For Typo3 8 following approach worked:

```
$tce = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler::class);
$tce->clear_cacheCmd($pid);
```

Using this in Typo3 9 causes this error:

> Call to a member function getTSConfig() on null
> in E:\wwwroot_T9LTS\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\DataHandling\DataHandler.php line 8971

What is the best approach to clear cache for a page id in Typo3 9?

**Update**
got it to work using CacheManager:

```
$cacheManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\CacheManager::class);
$cacheManager->flushCachesInGroupByTags('pages', [ 'pageId_'.$pid ]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably run into problems using the DataHandler to clear the cache when not logged in to the backend. In Extbase context you may use:

```
$cacheManager = $this->objectManager->get(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Service\CacheService::class);
$cacheManager->clearPageCache([1,2,3]);
```

Comment: thanks for this answer, thats probably the best solution, however it is an old pi-Extension. Got it still working with CacheManager

Comment: It should also work in pi-based extensions. You'll just need to get the ObjectManager: `$objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance( \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager::class );`

Answer (score 1):

You will have to initialize the class by calling the start() method:

```php
$tce = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler::class);
$tce->start([], []);
$tce->clear_cacheCmd($pid);
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/9.5/en-us/ApiOverview/Typo3CoreEngine/UsingDataHandler/Index.html#clearing-cache) for details.

Comment: I tried this before, but I had to be loggend in to the backend. Like Paul Beck mentioned.
Solved the problem and updated my post

Comment: Good to know. Thx for the hint.